# "Server Rejected Request" (15/2001); "Request failed with http status code 500"

Tags: ios, cloudkit

`fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler` returns:

`<CKError 0x14daad30: "Server Rejected Request" (15/2001); "Request failed with http status code 500">`

I have never seen this error with `CloudKit`. Do you think it is associated that some iCloud service was down nowadays?

```
defaultContainer.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({ _userRecordID, error in

        if error == nil {

            userRecordID = _userRecordID
            loggedInUserRecordName = _userRecordID.recordName
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                self.progressView.setProgress(2 / self.steps, animated: true)
            })

        } else {

            Utility.log("error 1231: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sema)
    })
```

Strange that `fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler` works in one of my other project with an other container, but **usually** does not work with this project with this container.

Any idea way?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a server issue at the other end. 500 error code is unexpected internal error at server.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you are using wrong container. In my project I was using custom container that did not match default app container. Switching to correct one with custom identifier solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **id** of the CKContainer in Capabilities and your CKContainer's initialization make ensure that they are the same. In my case, I make this mistake， and the error?.localizedDescription is Optional("Request failed with http status code 500")